# Understanding Prometheus JVM metrics

Tags: jvm, prometheus, metrics, jmx, datadog

I am interested in tracking two metrics within JVM - Number of GCs per minute and Time Spent in GC per minute. I have metrics `jvm_gc_collection_seconds.count` and `jvm_gc_collection_seconds.sum` available with me on the dashboard but I am a little confused about their meaning.

The first metric `jvm_gc_collection_seconds.count` seems like it has something to do with measuring time but reading up on it I believe it is the number of times GC was invoked from the start of time (when application started).

1. Is this right?
2. If so why is there the word "seconds" in the metric name?
3. Would `jvm_gc_collection_seconds.count/1 minute` give me the number of GC invocation per minute?

The second metric `jvm_gc_collection_seconds.sum` I believe is the total time spent doing GC activity in seconds from the start of time.

1. Is that right?
2. Would `jvm_gc_collection_seconds.sum/1 minute` give me the time spent in seconds doing GC activity in a 1 minute time window?

Comment: could you check your `/metrics` endpoint and search for `jvm_gc_collection_seconds`? apart from `_sum` and `_count` there should be a metric with `quantile` label

Comment: @star67 no, there isn't one with quantile showing up on datadog. I haven't explicitely queries /metrics endpoint myself. But since datadog is configured to do so I am assuming it would have fetched it if there was one (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jvm_gc_collection_seconds` is a [summary metric](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary).

> A summary with a base metric name of `<basename>` exposes multiple time series during a scrape:
>
> - streaming *φ-quantiles* (0 ≤ φ ≤ 1) of observed events, exposed as `<basename>{quantile="<φ>"}`
> - the total sum of all observed values, exposed as `<basename>_sum`
> - the count of events that have been observed, exposed as `<basename>_count`

So `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count` has as a total value number of GC events that took place since application start. And `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum` - total number of seconds taken by all those events.

To get the number of GC invocation per minute you can use `increase(jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count [1m])`. And similarly for time spent: `increase(jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum [1m])`.

---

Additionally, you might find some helpful tips regarding JVM metrics regarding garbage collection in [this post](https://www.robustperception.io/measuring-java-garbage-collection-with-prometheus/) by Brian Brazil.

Comment: "So jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count has as a total value number of GC events that took place since application start. And jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count - total number of seconds taken by all those events." - 

Did you mean some other metric? You have used "jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count" to describe both the cases.

Comment: @Ashwin, oops, sorry, wrong copy-paste.

Comment: got it. "increase(jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count [1m])" does this mean the difference between the two values of the metric 1 minute apart?

Comment: @Ashwin, yes (with automatic processing of conter resets). But it's a promql query, I only now noticed that you are using datadog. I'm not familiar with it, so no idea how to write it in its language.